# Redirect to subdomain route with www site using .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website in which I have htaccess configured to redirect all the traffic to www website. So my website works like this: www.domain.com

Now I want to support subdomain feature for all the registered users for example username.domain.com but my current htaccess rules don't allow this when I hit such URL then it redirects subdomain URL to include www as well which I don't want. 
For example:

I hit username.domain.com and it becomes www.username.domain.com

Here is my current htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How do I support both www for main site? So that when user hits subdomain URL then it should not add www in the URL.

I am not expert in URL rewriting, so apologies if I miss something obvious.

Thanks

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: @anubhavamy apache version is 2.4.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Apache `2.4+` you can use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if not main domain skip all rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: If you can specify the domain name it's easier. Let me know if this is not the case.

Comment: Thank you @Croises. It has solved the redirection problem but now my main site traffic going to subdomain route as well. For example: www.domain.com and username.domain.com are hitting the same route and I am unable to access my primary website i.e without subdomain.
Any help?

Comment: Give me examples of what you want to do.

Comment: Rewrite the subdomains to something else?

Comment: I want that when user types www.domain.com then it should run my main website and all other urls should correspond to their controllers and actions. 
But if I type subdomain url e.g username.domain.com then it should be handled by specific controller's action in my application. The redirection code you gave is solving the redirection problem but since www in www.domain is treated as username in my application all www.domain.com is going to that controller action that is handling subdomain route.

Comment: I still do not understand well. Do you want to rewrite them all to index.php or not? If it's not, I think the @anubhava solution should be right for you.